# Password recovery

Tags: active-directory, windows-xp, password

An employee has just recently quit. I have access to our domain control of which active directory sits upon. Unfortunately the employee did not leave us with his password to log into his local machine. Is there a way for me to go into active directory and change his password or allow myself into his box under his login credentials to clean up his account?

Comment: Cue loads of password recovery tool spam ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have Domain Admin privileges on the domain you should be able to go into Active Directory Users and Computers, select his account, right click and select "Change Password." You should then be able to log in as that account with the new password.

Answer (score 3):

If you are a domain admin on your network, then you can simply change that user's password to something you know and then log in as that user.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to log in as him?  If you want to clean out his account, then just log in as yourself ( being an admin ), and delete his user profile directory, and then his account.